# Display links in table based on value

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I want to be able to display links based on cell values.

So if I have this table:

```
    <tr style="background-color:#576c11;">
    <td style="font-size:18px; color:#f0cb01;">'.$data["keyword"].'</td>
    <td style="font-size:18px;color:#f0cb01;">'.$data["block"].'</td>
    <td style="font-size:18px;color:#f0cb01;">'.$data["phone"].'</td>
    <td style="font-size:18px;color:#f0cb01;">'.$data["Reason"].'</td>
```

And I want to display a 5th cell to display a link based on the reason cell, how can I accomplish that?

So if reason cell is 65 then the next cell would be `<a href="65.html">Link</a>`
for the most part they will all be the same but some cells will differ.

Comment: Have you attempted anything?  What have you tried?

Comment: This may also be added to the form so if reason = 65 then it will place link 65.html in the database.

Comment: @bretterer im looking for a jump off point to be honest

Comment: Look at using some jquery.  Find the reason code and append a new td from there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way your input is formatted, this is part of some larger string, beginning somewhere with a single quote you have not copied, and ending somewhere else with another single quote you have not copied. Correct behaviour depends very much on what the context enclosing that string is.

If you're assembling a string in a variable, you could simply do a case distinction using `if` to decide what string to append next, based in the reason. If this is a string passed to some function, perhaps you *should* assemble it in a variable, the way I just described, and then pass that result to the function. If there is some very good reason this has to be a single expression, you could use the conditional operator:

```
'…'.($data["Reason"] == 65 ? 'It is 65' : 'It is not 65').'…'
```